# How can I disable JavaScript in Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: internet-explorer-10

I'm running Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7. In the <kbd>F12</kbd> developer tools, `Script` is faded out on the `Disable` menu. JavaScript *is* working, but I'd like to turn it off. How can I do so? Is there any reason the `Disable` menu entry is faded out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Adjust Internet Explorer active scripting settings

Windows validation might not run properly if your web browser is not configured to allow active scripting. To allow active scripting so that validation can run properly, do the following:

1. Open Internet Explorer.
2. Click the Tools menu, and then click Internet Options.
3. On the Security tab, click the Custom level button.
4. Scroll down the Security Settings list until you see Scripting and Active scripting.
5. Click Disable, click OK, and then click OK again.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/help/genuine/ie-active-script)

Comment: What on earth is Windows Validation?

Comment: This works. I'd still be interested to know why the Menu doesn't work though. Interestingly, after doing this method, a tick is shown (still grayed out) in the menu next to Script.

Comment: Thank you for the edit I missed that :-) For the other stuff you should add some code.

Comment: there's no code to add, this is just a setting in the debug tools, it applies to all websites.

Comment: I think I missunderstood that part. You mean you want to disable the developer tools or better just the js part. Not sure how that works...